# ANT parameter passing by reference

Tags: apache, ant, parameter-passing

I am very new to ANT scripting and am using it for automating daily build's in my project. I am using it more in the sense of scripting (XML files) and aggregate pre-existing features and come up with build process.

I feel I have some basic understanding problem with the antcall/target concept. Especially when antcall is made with parameter, Like C++, is there a way to call target will parameter as  pass by reference? so that value changed in the target can be retrieved by the caller?

In the below example, I want to check if two files are same and display the result, but for the below example, I would get the output as

---

Are Same Files : ${isFileName}

---

Example:

`< target name="checkFileAreSame">`
`< condition property="isFileSame">`
`< filesmatch file1="a.txt" file2="b.txt"/>`
`< /condition >`
`< /target >`

`< target name="Maintask">`
`< antcall target="checkFileAreSame">`
`< param name="isFileSame" value="false">`
`< /antcall >`
`< echo message="Are files Same : ${isFileSame}"/>`
`< /target >`

---

Thanks for your input in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ant [properties are immutable](http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html) - once set, their values cannot be changed.

When using the [`antcall` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/antcall.html) note that:

> The called target(s) are run in a new
>   project; be aware that this means
>   properties, references, etc. set by
>   called targets will not persist back
>   to the calling project.

But also note that the properties that you pass to the called target using 'antcall' `param` attributes are immutable in the called target.
That means that in the 'condition' task example given:

```
<condition property="isFileSame">
    <filesmatch file1="a.txt" file2="b.txt"/>
</condition>
```

the `isFileSame` property is already set to `false` by the caller, and so will remain false regardless of the file comparison.

It's more common to [declare dependencies between targets](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html) in this sort of way:

```
<target name="checkFileAreSame">
    <condition property="isFileSame">
        <filesmatch file1="a.txt" file2="b.txt"/>
    </condition>
</target>

<target name="Maintask" depends="checkFileAreSame">
    <echo message="Are files Same : ${isFileSame}"/>
</target>
```

Ant will determine the call graph for 'Maintask' requires that 'checkFileAreSame' be run first.

Comment: +1 for the advice to use dependencies instead of [`<antcall>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/antcall.html)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need AntCallBack task from ant-contrib package (separate from core Ant).

Ant-contrib is a very useful library if you aren't happy (like many) with Ant's "declarative" flow style.

See here:

http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/

http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html

http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/antcallback_task.html